# Ehcache, Hibernate, updating cache of very large table when a new entry is added?

Tags: database, hibernate, ehcache

I'm new to Ehcache and am searching on how to do this but now quite sure if this is a normal use case. I am working on an application that isn't a traditional web app, its something that is only used by a few people at a time and is for retrieving data from a very large dataset so rather than making a call to the DB each time I want to use caching to cache this large table. However, there is a chance that a new entry could be added to this table and I need this reflected in the cache but I don't want to reload the entire cache each time as its quite large. Any advice on how to approach this / further resources is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about Hibernate [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache). In simple words: it works on top of second level cache (`L2`) and stores results of queries. **But** it only stores ids of the records that should be returned by the query rather than a whole list. This means that you need to have L2 working and fine tuned.

In your scenario suppose you have 1M records in table `T` and a query that returns 1K by average. The first time you run this query it will miss the query cache and:

1. run the SQL
2. fetch 1K records
3. put all of them in L2
4. put 1K *ids* in query cache

The next time you execute the query it will hit the query cache and lookup all the result from L2. The interesting part comes when you modify table `T`. Hibernate will figure out that the results in query cache might be stale and it will invalidate the whole cache but not the L2. It will basically repeat points 1-4 but refreshing only query cache (most of entities from table `T` are already in L2).

In some scenarios it works great, in others it introduces N+1 problems in unpredictable moments. This is just a tip of an iceberg, you should be really careful as this mechanism is very fragile and requires great understanding.

Comment: Just an additional comment: "Hibernate will figure out that the results in query cache might be stale and it will invalidate the whole cache but not the L2". Hibernate will invalidate your query cache whenever the application hits the tables used by the query (to update, insert, delete data) or from time to time (whatever occurs first). So, if you change your data in the database directly, Hibernate will not know about it and may return stale results while it thinks the cache is still valid (ie: missing data).